# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2n+2)!!\cdot (2n+1)!!}{(2n+3)!!\cdot (2n)!!}$

Tags: limits

> Evaluation of limit of the form  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2n+2)!!\cdot (2n+1)!!}{(2n+3)!!\cdot (2n)!!}$$

process i have $\displaystyle n!=n!!\cdot (n-1)!!$

$\displaystyle n!!=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!!}$

$$(2n)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-1)!!}$$

$$(2n+2)!!=\frac{(2n+2)!}{(2n+1)!!}$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: So the numerator simplifies to $(2n+2)!$  Now simplify the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(2n+2)!!=(2n+2)(2n)!!,(2n+3)!!=(2n+3)(2n+1)!! That should help you to solve it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Observe $$\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n)!!} = 2n+2$$ and $$\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+3)!!} = \frac{1}{2n+3}.$$